# WCF Service over HTTPS only

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, https, iis-7.5

I have a RESTful WCF service that I want to host on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  It's currently hosted as an Application within an existing website.  A self-signed certificate is being used for port 443.

I'd like the service to be served over HTTPS only. In the SSL Settings for the Application, I've set it to "Require SSL".  The endpoint configuration is as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Rest">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="ACME.MyAuthorizationManager, ACME.WS.Authorization" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>

  <webHttpEndpoint>

    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

However, I'm receiving 403 responses when trying to access the service via a browser (e.g. `https://example.com/myservices/baz-service/yip-resource`).

Did I miss anything during configuration?

Comment: How are you trying to access the service? From a browser or from a wcf proxy?

Comment: what does the Binding/Endpoint configuration look like for your svc?

Comment: Initial attempt to access is being done via a browser.  I've added the endpoint config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the "Require SSL" option on IIS means that you are performing authentication using client certificates. Just set that option to ignore or disable that option if you dont have any client certificate authentication.

To avoid your service to serve only on HTTPS remove the HTTP binding from the "Binding" option on your website. Else just expose your bindings to use transport as a security mechanism and that should take care of your WCF service being served only on HTTPS.

UPDATE:

Please find on how I have a RESTful service hosted on IIS with Https:

```
[ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class RestService
    {
        // TODO: Implement the collection resource that will contain the SampleItem instances

        private static List<SampleItem> sampleCollection = new List<SampleItem>();

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/get-Collection")]
        public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
        {
            // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
            if (sampleCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                sampleCollection = new List<SampleItem>();
                sampleCollection.Add(new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello 1" });
                sampleCollection.Add(new SampleItem() { Id = 2, StringValue = "Hello 2" });
                sampleCollection.Add(new SampleItem() { Id = 3, StringValue = "Hello 3" });
                sampleCollection.Add(new SampleItem() { Id = 4, StringValue = "Hello 4" });
                sampleCollection.Add(new SampleItem() { Id = 5, StringValue = "Hello 5" });
            }
            return sampleCollection;
        }
}
```

My Global.asax:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes();
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RestService)));
        }
    }
```

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000">          
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />          
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="localhost" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now my IIS has the Https binding specified:

[image: Site Bindings in IIS]

Now my virtual directory has been configured with the name XmlRestService and hence when i browse to the resource i get the below output:

[image: Output from a REST Service on HTTPS]

Comment: I currently have "Client certificates" set to Ignore.

Comment: You dont need to have the readerQuotas section but if your service has to send large amount of data its better to leave it.

Comment: Using that standardEndpoint results in the following:

Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Comment: Please find my sample app that I have posted that gets information from a REST based WCF service using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to implement WCF. This answer like many did not work for me. I came up with the following quick solution. I think it is probably the most universal and simple solution. This may not be considered eloquent but for most of us that's not appreciated in our work anyway. You could try a redirect, at least for GET requests, instead of throwing an error.

```
#if !DEBUG
    // check secure connection, raise error if not secure 
    IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
    if (!request.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        throw new WebProtocolException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Https is required to use this service.", null);
    }
#endif
```